# Load Google Markers using MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, mysqli

I've looked up other examples of this question on Stack, but they either use JQUERY or load using XML etc, which is NOT what I'm using to populate my Map.

Map works perfectly fine, but marker doesn't work when I attempt to reference a PHP variable as LatLng. I've tried to echo the LatLng Variable and use Heredocs but nothing works.

```
<? php
    // I MADE QUERIES HERE AND ADDED THEM INTO "$coords"


echo<<<_

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="Banner">
        <div class="TitleText">Sonic Strains &copy;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="login">Logout</div>
    <div class="gallery" id="container">
        <div class="map" id="mapInsert"></div>
        <div class="navButton">Start Nav</div><div class="orderButton">Order Details</div>
        <div class="abortButton">Abort</div><div class="confirmButton">Confirm</div><div class="disclaimer"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
          function initMap() {  
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapInsert'));
                Map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                Map.setZoom(8);
            }, function(positionError) {
                //---------- User denied geolocation prompt - default to Chicago
                Map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.8097343, -98.5556199));
                Map.setZoom(5);
            },{enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 3000, maximumAge:1000});}
                //MAKE ANOTHER MARKER FOR THE CLIENT LOCATION
                var userLocation = {lat:$coords[user_lat], lng:$coords[user_long]};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:userLocation, 
                    map:Map,
                    draggable:false, 
                    clickable:false
                });
                marker.setMap(Map);}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]&callback=initMap" 
        async defer></script>
    </body>
    </html>


_;

?>
```

**Error--**

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

This is where I try an reference the PHP LatLng Marker Position, why doesn't it allow me to reference PHP?

Comment: Need to let us know what line you are getting your syntax error, from just looking over it quickly I can see an error on line: var userLocation = {lat:<?php $coords[user_lat]?>, lng: <?php $coords[user_long]?>}; it should be var userLocation = {lat:<?php $coords['user_lat'];?>, lng: <?php $coords['user_long'];?>};

Comment: That's the line

Comment: The Added '' & ; didn't make a difference, still getting the same error.

Comment: Try <?php echo $coords[user_lat]; ?>

Comment: I've stated in the original question that I've tried to echo but still get the same error.

Comment: What's the filename?

Comment: Sakura, why is the filename important, couldn't you name it whatever you want to run the code?

Comment: Normally, PHP code only runs on .php files, except if you configure your webserver to do something different.... In that case, your PHP code are not running, I think the filename is VERY relevant.

Comment: @user615274 is correct would need to echo it, missed that. the file would also need to have the .php extension to run the php code

Comment: I've tried to echo it already with same error and does it not already have the PHP tags inline? Second2None

Comment: driverIndex.php if you wanted to know the filename

Comment: If the file are .php... try to change the first shorttag (<?) to a complete tag (<?php), and check on HTML code on client side if you see these text on the first PHP comment. Apparently, php is not running.

Comment: Just confirming the file was actually a php file. When you view source code what is displayed?

Comment: When I DONT comment out the marker, the map displays perfectly, but when I allow the Marker code to run, it screws up the map from being displayed altogether and throws an extra "initmap()" is not a function w/ the aformentioned "SyntaxError"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the marker declaration was outside of the initMap(). When I moved the marker inside of the Main Function it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the opening tag. You're using an invalid tag:

```
<? php
```

(note the blank between question and PHP keyword).

You need to change it to a correct opening PHP tag, as:

```
<?php
```

Also, on the code, you need to echo the vars, because you're not doing anything with it.

```
var userLocation = {lat:<?php echo $coords[user_lat]; ?>, lng: <?php echo $coords[user_long]; ?>};
```

**((EDIT))**

Ok, doing a new revision to the code, I can see at least one problem:

You're creating a POI with this syntax:

```
            var userLocation = {lat:$coords[user_lat], lng:$coords[user_long]};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:userLocation, 
                map:Map,
                draggable:false, 
                clickable:false
            });
```

Checking on my own code, there's a functional poi adding code:

```
    newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        key: marker[0],
        name: marker[1],
        lat: marker[3],
        lon: marker[4],
        content: marker[9],
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker[3], marker[4]),
        icon: icon
    });
```

Probably, lot of the code (key, name, etc) are optional values, but, you're adding an array to position value, and not a LatLng value.

If that code doesn't work, please check your HTML code directly (not on PHP), because you can have something strange on the code blocking the loading process (For example, php is not filling the values correctly).

Comment: This is super frustrating because I've tried to echo the code many times, but get the same result. Can any1 try and run a simple query and reference it inline?

Comment: Did you try to fix your shorttag opening? I have a webpage when I define variables on PHP and I use it on javascript using a <script> and var=<?php echo $phpVar; ?> working without problem.

Comment: The tags are cleaned up and the Local Server is running.

Comment: SyntaxError are from PHP or from JavaScript?? Also, if you want you can come to SO chat on PHP channel to try to view it on a more detail maybe...

Comment: Forget it about chat. You need more reputation for doing it. I really didn't see anything bad on your code for not work echoing a variable. The only option I think who can be are a error on the code not posted here. It's because this I've told you for check PHP error log... Also, check HTML code on client-side for if it's here anything strange (for example something before the <HTML> tag). If you find something, please edit your question to complete the information.

Comment: I tried using Heredocs (code changed above) and got a new error-- "Reference Error" - google is not defined . The error appears after the LatLng used for the Marker. "new google.maps.Marker"

Comment: Anyone know why I get a "Reference Error: google is not defined" error when using HEREDOC?

Comment: Did you check HTML code? Have you try to force the coordinates for verify the rest of the code are correct?

Comment: The map loads fine but the marker isn't populating because the "google.maps.Marker" class isn't being recognized when the marker is being created.  --    "Reference Error: google is not defined"

Comment: I've edited the answer. Check if this new information helps you.

Comment: What does the acronym POI stand for? Tried to google but it came up with a weird looking Hawaiian Dish and something to do with Apache. I'm sure you mean something else.